# Streaming music on your website through custom player / application (iTunes)

Tags: itunes

I was doing some research to find out ways that would allow me to stream music on my website legally. I came across iTunes partner program which allows to stream music on a website through their embedded players. I was wondering is it possible to stream iTunes music through your own custom player? If that is not possible via iTunes, then what other methods are available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a server software like Icecast, there is some good tutorials on setting this up here: http://www.icecast.org/docs.php

Depending on how many browsers you want to support you might want to setup two streams, one in MP3/OGG and a "backup" stream in Flash. Then add some detection as to what the browser supports and present the correct stream (i.e.: Use the HTML5 `<audio>` tag for playing MP3/OGG to browsers that support this, and use your flash stream for the rest)

Answer (score -2):

their program allowing playback of music in the iTunes Store is likely only for those with the intention to sell music, without providing a commerce business, you'd be breaking their partner program T&C's.

Comment: Yeh, website would be based on e-comerce for selling music, but the question is if it's possible to stream it through your custom made player?